# reset form without changing select's selected

Tags: javascript, forms

suppose that I have a form with one input with `type=text` one select and one input with type=`button`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm">
      <input type="text" id="textInput" />
      <input type="button" value="click" id="myBtn" />
      <select name="selector" id="mySelect">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    <script>
      const button = document.getElementById('myBtn');
      const form = document.getElementById('myForm');
      const inputText = document.getElementById('inputText');
      const selector = document.getElementById('mySelect');

      button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        //do some stuff here
        form.reset();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

as you can see, at the end of buttons click event listener, I call `form.reset()` which will reset everything in the form to their default value but I don't want the value of selector to be reset. if I wanted the value of inputText to stay intact I could use `inputText.defaultValue = inputText.value" and then calling` form.reset()` would not change it's value. can I do something like that but for selector?

notes:

1- I'm learning JS and can't use any jquery or things like that.

2- I know that instead of calling `form.reset()` I can manually reset values of everything inside form except selector but in the actual example there are lots of stuff inside form and that option is a last resort.

3-sorry for bad English

Comment: you can create a loop for the form and check the element which one you want to reset values and which one not

Comment: Inside the event handler function, first grab the current value of the `<select>` and store it in a variable, call `form.reset()` and finally set the value of the `<select>` back to what it has been.